# Set component providers depending on @input

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-material

I would use [material datepicker with selection strategy](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#date-range-picker-selection-strategy)

Sometimes I should not use the selection strategy.

But like it is instanciated in the providers array . I can't find a way to set it or not conditionally.

```
import { Component, Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import {
  MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy,
  DateRange,
  MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Injectable()
export class FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy<D>
  implements MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy<D>
{
  constructor(private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>) {}

  selectionFinished(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(date);
  }

  createPreview(activeDate: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(activeDate);
  }

  private _createFiveDayRange(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    if (date) {
      const start = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, -2);
      const end = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, 2);
      return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
    }

    return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
  }
}

/** @title Date range picker with custom a selection strategy */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-range-picker-selection-strategy',
  templateUrl: 'date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useClass: FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy,
    },
  ],
})
export class DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample {
  @Input() set selectionStrategy(value:boolean) {
    if(value) {
      //// Sould provide selection strategy
    }
    else {
     //// sould not
    }
  };
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p><b>Sould use selection strategy</b></p>
<app-date-range-picker-selection-strategy [selectionStrategy]="true"></app-date-range-picker-selection-strategy>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<p><b>Sould <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}">not</span> use selection strategy</b></p>
<app-date-range-picker-selection-strategy [selectionStrategy]="false"></app-date-range-picker-selection-strategy>
```

Actually I'm creating two date-picker components : one with selection Strategy and one without.

I would like to know **how can I use only one component for the two use cases** ?

I have read a lot about `useValue/useFactory/useClass` but I didn't get to the solution.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evuj51?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: Just my opinion, but it seems like it would be easier to have 2 date pickers. One with the selection strategy and one without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `useFactory` option like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-range-picker-selection-strategy',
  templateUrl: 'date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useFactory: (
        comp: DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample,
        adapter: DateAdapter<unknown> 
      ) => {
        return comp.selectionStrategy
          ? new FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy(adapter)
          : null;
      },
      deps: [DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample, DateAdapter],
    },
  ],
})
export class DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample {
  @Input() selectionStrategy!: boolean;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evuj51-qm5rxo)**

Comment: you wrote `useExisting` but I don't see it in your code ? did you mean `useFactory` ?

Comment: @HamzaHaddad Sorry, that's was a typo. I meant `useFactory`

Comment: ried your example , the `comp` variable is always `undefined` :/

Comment: @HamzaHaddad Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: I'm asking because I tested it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evuj51-jrew8s Open browser console and try to open first datepicker

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evuj51-w881p4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts,src%2Findex.html

Comment: You forgot to add `deps` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evuj51-ucb6pf

Comment: Almost ok ! The problem now is that I'm getting this when I hover datepicker ( selection Strategy `true` ) : `this._rangeStrategy.createPreview is not a function`

Comment: I am also trying to make it work using this suggested solution. However, it does not seem to work in my case. i put a console.log inside the useFactory code block and it does not seem to be called.